# Nginx(proxy) + Apache: two process listening same port

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, centos

I have two servers on CentOS: Nginx(proxy) + Apache.
I need restart Nginx but if i try to test configuration before restart, i have next error:

```
[root@vm5808 ~]# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

How i can solve this problem? Thanks!

P.S. Nginx has listen port 80, apache listen 81.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why this error has appeared, but after I made

```
[root@vm5808 ~]# /etc/init.d/nginx stop  
Stopping nginx:                                            [  OK  ]
[root@vm5808 ~]# /etc/init.d/nginx start
Starting nginx:                                            [  OK  ]
```

error has gone:

```
[root@vm5808 ~]# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

I've tried `restart` before `stop` and `start`, but Nginx wouldn't restart:

```
[root@vm5808 ~]# /etc/init.d/nginx restart
nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: Maybe nginx wasnt detecting two instances. Anyway next time try a netstat --program --listening --numeric (or -npl in short way) to discover the pid of the process in that port

Comment: @PerroVerd I have try `netstat -tanup | grep 80` and i have 
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      8400/nginx`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is simple, you seem to have both nginx and apache listening on port 80, so nginx finds the port already in use, you need to move apache to another port, like 81 for example, and make nginx listen on 80, because it's the one which is going to receive the http requests and proxy it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But look at P.S. in my question ;)

Comment: well to make sure stop the apache service and start nginx, if it starts then it's apache's fault for holding port 80

Answer (score 0):

Check all the virtualhosts in apache, probably one of them is listening on port 80

Comment: Thanks for tip, but they listen port 81. I have already check.